# Get all real analytics data having condition 'custom:user_id="XYZ"'?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I tried to automate test to validate GA events.

My approach is :-

1. List item use google analytics real time reporting api.
2. Before the test ends i will hit this api and collect the last 30 mins data
3. This data will be a huge chunk of formattedJson string 
   and in this string i will search my GA events which was supposed to push.

This approach seems to be in-efficient.

My issue is to find the analytics data which corresponds to test user.

Each user has unique user id, hence, i am trying for making the request such that api returns me the filtered data based on some custom dimension `"custom:user_id='user_unique_id'"` .

Is it possible to get all data having condition e.g `'custom:user_id="XYZ"'`.

Please advise, how to get all ga events data for a specific event label / custom dimension ? Also, does it support **dimensionFilterClauses** like reporting api v4 ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by filtering.

e.g `rt:eventCategory==ProductPage`

earlier i was using quote, `rt:eventCategory=='ProductPage'` which wasn't supported.